# How to select column in sqlalchemy exists

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

The [SQLAlchemy exists docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.exists) say that using `exists` creates a SQL statement with `EXISTS (SELECT 1 ...)`. How can I get `EXISTS` to select a column of my choosing?

I have two models likes so:

```
class Query:
    id = Column(UUID)
    content = Column(String)
    ...

class Review:
    id = Column(UUID)
    query_id = Column(UUID, ForeignKey('query.id'))
    ...
```

I'm trying to perform a complex query which requires getting all the `id`s `Query`s  which don't have a `Review`. To do this I've written the following python:

```py
reviewed_query_ids_sql_query = session.query(models.Review.query_id)

filtered_queries_sql_query = session.query(models.Query.id).where(~reviewed_query_ids_sql_query.exists())
```

but that's producing the following SQL for `filtered_queries_sql_query`:

```
SELECT queries.id 
FROM queries 
WHERE (EXISTS (SELECT 1 
FROM reviews))
```

However, the raw query for `reviewed_query_ids_sql_query` is

```
SELECT reviews.query_id AS reviews_query_id 
FROM reviews
```

How come the exists does a `SELECT 1` when the underlying query does a `SELECT <column>`? What I'd like for the query to do is `SELECT query_id FROM reviews` in the query with the `EXISTS` clause. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, though I'm not sure if it's optimal:

```
from sqlalchemy import exists

reviewed_query_ids_sql_query = ~exists(
    session.query(models.Review.query_id)
        .filter(models.Query.id == models.Review.query_id)
        .enable_eagerloads(False).with_labels().statement)

filtered_queries_sql_query = session.query(models.Query.id).where(reviewed_query_ids_sql_query)
```

I use the functions `.enable_eagerloads(False).with_labels().statement` because those are used in the underlying implementation of [`exists`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.exists) and I think they improve performance (though I'm not sure and haven't dug in).